# Logitech external keyboard stopped working after Ubuntu 20.10 and also 21.04

Tags: kernel, keyboard, logitech

I am really starting to find this annoying as I was hoping after an upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 the problem would be gone but it's still here.

Everything works except the logitech external usb keyboard.

```
uname -a
5.11.0-22-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:34:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 5986:211b Acer, Inc HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:009b Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:0a29 Logitech, Inc. H600 [Wireless Headset]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0000:0538   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2101:8501 ActionStar USB HID
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2101:8500 ActionStar USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So far kernel 5.8.0 does not work (Ubuntu 20.10) and kernel 5.11.0 (Ubuntu 21.04) also does not work. If I manually select kernel 4.15.0 the keyboard works again. I had a setup to always start with that kernel but I am looking for a better solution to use the latest kernel. I also don't want to reinstall the system if possible. I tried logging in with Ubuntu Xorg but that does not work
I also tried going to `/etc/modprobe.d` and see if anything was blacklisted that did not make sense. I did find `blacklist usbkbd` so I disabled that but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Update: it's an msi PS42 8M laptop, keyboard logitech k270

Comment: found this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1912908 but it has not been fixed yet

Comment: im running 20.04 LTS, actual kernel version is 5.8.0-59 - using ubuntu since 2006, i always use LTS versions to get rid of issues like the one you are facing - have a good day

Comment: Which of the 5 models [here](https://www.msi.com/Content-Creation/support/PS42-8RX) is yours?
Brand/model of the keyboard?

Comment: The firmware may be updated at some point, if you wait (sorry that's not very helpful) but then you can try `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` and see if it finds any updates.

Comment: Thanks for all who replied, got sick of trying so got a cable (usb) keyboard by TeckNet and now it works. The issue was with the usb cordless keyboard. Hope this gets fixed in the future